# Tag block request: [best-practice]

Tags: support, status-completed, stack-overflow, tag-block-request

Per Jeff's blog post ([The Death of Meta Tags](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/)), we should not be using `best-practices` tag. Question here asked 1 hour ago uses the **`best-practice`**: [Is it better to return the most specific or most general type from an action method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3434367/is-it-better-to-return-the-most-specific-or-most-general-type-from-an-action-meth)

Can we block `best-practice` tag and similar variations?

Comment: Do similar variations include [subjective] and [beginner]? Those have both been recreated too; I [mentioned](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/chats/message/59939?offset=-240) it in the chat yesterday

Comment: @Michael: It should to a certain extent

Comment: best-practices is my favorite tag!  Wha happeh?

Comment: +1 for sharing Jeff's blog post. I used to favorite the `best-practices` tag for its value as a potpourri learning tool, but now I understand its subjectivity is harmful. A better way to learn is to _choose topics you want to learn about_, favorite their tags, and read the highlighted questions. After two years, I'm unfavoriting this obsolete tag!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ok, I added a question mark to the end of the best-practices blacklist entry.