# Could the 'project-ideas' tag on Stack Overflow be eliminated?

Tags: support, tag-block-request

[project-ideas](/questions/tagged/project-ideas) currently has <strike>115</strike> 75 questions, a bunch of which are already closed, the rest (after a quick perusal) pretty much all fall into either:

- Not constructive,
- Not a real question, or
- Plain off-topic

close reasons, in my opinion. I'm having a hard time coming up with questions that could both be on topic for Stack Overflow and require this tag.
The ['12 tag cleansing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/128315/the-great-stack-overflow-tag-question-cleanup-of-2012) even attacked it, marking it as "Do not use, removed".

Could [project-ideas](/questions/tagged/project-ideas) be purged? Or should it be kept as a sign-post for questions that need closing, like [career-development](/questions/tagged/career-development)?

Comment: Users won't stop asking these questions just because the tag is no longer available.  Eliminating it just makes it harder to filter them out.

Comment: Good point. So you wouldn't have supported something like [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60118/tag-block-request-best-practice)?

Comment: Oooh, a good source of questions to vote to close/delete!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How are tags removed if they aren't used by at least 2 questions in 6 months?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/325144/how-are-tags-removed-if-they-arent-used-by-at-least-2-questions-in-6-months)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Most people using that tag are either looking for programmers or looking for a quick solution ("I want this, gief"-questions), so I'm absolutely for this!