# Remove [project] tag?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, retag-request, burninate-request

The [project](/questions/tagged/project) tag has over a thousand tagged questions, but doesn't seem to do a lot. Looking at the wiki, the description is very vague:

> In software development, a project is a collection of files and resources used in 
>   the development of an application or service.

The description is fairly unspecific and many of the questions go along the lines of "[How](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15608906/how-to-make-a-plagiarism-detector-in-python) [to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15611229/best-practice-for-multi-project-in-solution) [start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15617118/project-on-complaint-management-system-in-net-using-asp-net) [a](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15588209/agile-project-managers) [project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15622142/i-have-knowledge-on-java-and-oracle-i-want-to-do-one-project-by-using-the-java)?" Which goes against SO guidelines; having a tag that could suggest these questions are ok would be bad, much like [project-idea which was removed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118306/could-the-project-ideas-tag-on-stack-overflow-be-eliminated).

Many other questions, in my opinion, either don't need the tag to function, or are not truly pertaining to "project" but more to [their](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15507624/my-xcode-workspace-doesnt-remember-added-projects-when-restarted) [specific](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15602274/accidently-deleted-jre-from-my-eclipse-project) [workspace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15570666/diferente-betwen-different-project-files-in-netbeans) [or](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15500139/eclipse-and-maven-project-lifecycle-configuration) [ide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15620802/adding-files-to-project-dynamically).

The tag feels a bit redundant as there are already tags for specific ides like eclipse and netbeans (which many of the questions are already tagged as).

This also goes for [projects](/questions/tagged/projects).

Thoughts?

Comment: Just come across this tag, burninate it! P.S. if anyone's interested I'm out of close votes and this is the reason I came across it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2083020/need-some-advice-about-web-development-project

Comment: No, don't burninate.  Clean up *all* of the questions, and *then* burninate.  The tag is a honeypot.

Comment: Sorry @Charles, my personal version of burnination involves lots of closing and a little deletion first :-).