# Script to remove tags

Tags: discussion, feature-request, retag-request, burninate-request

There are some not useful or ambiguous tags which should be removed. As I know if a tag have no associated question it get removed after 24 hours.

But there are some questions, which have a number of question linked with:

[Burninate mysql-error-1064](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/177630/burninate-mysql-error-1064)

[Should the [close] tag be burninated?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/176903/should-the-close-tag-be-burninated)

[Remove Project tag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173482/remove-project-tag?rq=1)

It is difficult for users to untagged all the question? There should be a way to request for executing a script to remove unnecessary tags.

Answer (score 2):

We don't want to script tag removal in most cases.  If a question has a bad tag, odds are good that it has other problems as well.  We'd prefer it if someone took the time to look at each question individually and fix all of the problems (or vote to close/flag for a moderator) while removing the bad tag.

Answer (score 1):

> It is difficult for users to untagged all the question? There should
>   be a way to request for executing a script to remove unnecessary tags.

There is a way to get tags burninated and its by posting a [burninate-request](/questions/tagged/burninate-request) on MSO.

As far the difficulty in manual retagging goes, moderators and community managers have tools to perform mass retags in one go. However, its not possible for moderators to respond to every request hence, retags are done both manually, and sometimes by moderators, if they may come across your thread.

These tools are not accessible to normal users. If you want a change in that, then you should start a [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)

Comment: thanks for reply!!! actually I want something with a post that admin can differentiate which tags need the scripts to be run while which can be handle by users.

Comment: can i add a link to this question http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/184049/189547