# How are tags removed if they aren't used by at least 2 questions in 6 months?

Tags: support, tags, edits, tag-deletion

According to [the create new tags privilege page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/create-tags):

> However, note that:
>
> - on some sites, new tags will be automatically culled and removed from the system if they are not used by at least 1 other question in a 6 month period.
>
> ...

How does this happen? Is it an automatic revision from Community♦? Are the revisions actually edited so the tag is never shown (highly unlikely, but I don't know)? Or does it come in some other form?

I'm asking simply because I've never seen any auto-edits by Community♦ that remove unused tags, which makes me wonder if that's actually the way removing unused tags is accomplished.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are completely purged from the system; in other words, the full record of the tag is wiped out, and any existence of the tag is also erased from revision histories.

This process can also be done manually by an SE employee to any tag (known as "burninating" a tag), but some communities favor having the community manually edit the tags out of all questions to allow for a paper trail to be created and to allow for reviewing the questions using the tag.

Comment: Not sure why you brought up burnination at all here. It just adds extra words to the beginning of your answer that people need to read past. *shrugs* Most of us don't even like that term anyways. Just call it tag deletion. It's a lot clearer to everyone.