# How can I see whether a tag has been removed?

Tags: support, tags, tag-deletion

On one of the Stack Exchange websites, I suspect that a tag has been removed. How can I see whether a tag has been removed?

Comment: It is possible for the team to [fetch a list of removed tags from the database](https://meta.superuser.com/a/8230/222470) (see the "Appendix").

Comment: @SonictheAnti-NewVariant-hog thanks! Not possible for the regular users then?

Comment: Don't think so, as removed tags are effectively removed from question histories.

Comment: If you have a specific question in mind, you could have a look in the wayback machine.

Comment: @Luuklag thanks, I tried, but the question wasn't on wayback machine.

Comment: This question is unclear. The answer to the question I thought you asked is to go search on the tags page, which shows you if it exists as a tag or synonym or not.

Comment: @Laurel Thanks, I don't know how to make the question clearer. Could you please edit it, if you see a way to do so?

Comment: Possible cause: [How are tags removed if they aren't used by at least 2 questions in 6 months?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/325144/241919)

Comment: Maybe it's not 'without a trace, for everyone': https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/149385/282094 : "Since the tag silently disappears without a trace, it can be hard to restore the damage. If you happen to have ♦ privileges, you can recover the text of orphaned wikis, if you know where to look. But it's a hassle and a waste of time to fix tags that have been vandalised by the system.".

Answer (score 5):

I regularly encounter this situation when checking [untagged questions across the network](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/840855/untagged-questions-without-locks-networkwide). In those cases, there's no way to find the original tags, except the [Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/) if you're lucky. You can check both the question itself and the tag pages (`/tags/support`, `/questions/tagged/support`). FWIW, ♦ moderator tools are of no help here.

Of course, if you suspect a tag has been removed since last Sunday, you can check SEDE. Anyway, tag deletion other than by [Roomba](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/tag-pruning/info) (caused by lack of usage or a [burnination-request](/questions/tagged/burnination-request)) is (AFAIK) very rare.