# Calling the burninator: [good-design]

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, burninate-request

I've observed a surviving meta-y tag: [good-design](/questions/tagged/good-design), applied to 333 questions on SO. I can't find any question so tagged that [could stand on its own](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/). The only thing that gives me pause is that many of these questions aren't awful, but that's not a great reason to keep it around.

So, calling [Trogdor](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/121570/i-made-us-some-trogdor-graphics).

[image: Trogdor-signal]

Comment: Yup - seems very similar to the [best-practice?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60118/tag-block-request-best-practice) family of burnination and block to me.

Comment: The numerology would suggest it stays.  But the tag assassin in me says it goes.  Note: these questions *must* be checked for "not constructive" closings.  Don't just remove the tag.  Add a close vote and flag them if necessary (it probably is).

Answer (score 3):

As of sometime in the past, this has been completed. You no longer need to shine the Trogdor signal in the sky. [good-design](/questions/tagged/good-design) is gone (for now).